# How to use variables in for loop statements in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

So I'm trying to get this to roll an amount of dice equal to the specified input. To achieve this, I'm using a for loop, however it's not working.
As I just started coding recently, I have no idea why. Could someone please help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="number" id="diceamount" value="1">
<button onclick="FirstFunction()">Roll!</button>

<p id="display"></p>

<script>
var random = [];
document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = random;
a = document.getElementById("diceamount").innerHTML;


function FirstFunction() {
for (i=0; i<"a"; i++) {
    x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
    random.push(x);
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = random;
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does `i<"a"` mean? How many times do you expect the for loop to execute?

Comment: Input fields don't have an innerHTML.

Comment: The console within the Chrome developer tools (F12) will help you learn what properties are available to you. For instance, typing `document.getElementById("diceamount")` will give you back an object and you'll see which property holds the value you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you could do it. There are several issues highlighted in comments:

```js
function FirstFunction() {
    // Reset array within this function
    var random = [];
    // Get value property, and convert to number (with +)
    // And use var!
    var a = +document.getElementById("diceamount").value;
    // No quotes around a, and use var!
    for (var i=0; i<a; i++) {
        // Use var!
        var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
        random.push(x);
    }
    // Only show after the loop, and use textContent
    document.getElementById("display").textContent = random;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="diceamount" value="1">
<button onclick="FirstFunction()">Roll!</button>

<p id="display"></p>
```

Note that the array gets implicitly formatted as a comma separated value string when you display it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not how you define `"a"`.

This is how you do it:

```
for (i=0; i<a; i++) {
```

This is how you get the value from the text field:

```
var b = document.getElementById('textbox_id').value;
```

Then get the integer value:

```
var a = parseInt(b);
```

And then the for loop:

```
for (i=0; i<a; i++) {
```

Comment: Okay, that does work to some extent. however, it's supposed to give a string of numbers equal to a, it's however only giving one number as output no matter what input I give.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are doing it wrong ,...

Suppose you want to take the value of input which has id = "diceamount" 
so for that you have to store the value of the input in variable.

```
var a = document.getElementById('diceamount').value;
for(i = ; i<= a; i++){ 
 your code

}
```

**make this question down ; and look for some tutorials for javascript**

Comment: Thank you for your advice. It's much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var random = [];
// not useful? but in your code
document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = random;

function FirstFunction(event) {
    // get local value into a and use it the + avoids parseInt
    let a = Math.abs(+document.getElementById("diceamount").value);
    for (i=0; i<a; i++) {
      // x was not declared and should be
      let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
      random.push(x);
    }
    // could be textContent instead...outside loop
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = random;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="diceamount" value="1">
<button onclick="FirstFunction()">Roll!</button>
<p id="display">x</p>
```

Comment: NOTE having `random` outside the function means it keeps getting values appended, not sure you desired that.

Comment: With negative values entered for `a` -  made it positive using `Math.abs` not sure  that is a requirement